# Loading Animation from Kinect into Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, motion

I am designing a program that records the raw joint/jointPoint data for each body in each frame from the Kinect One sensor using the Kinect V2 SDK. Now, I need to take the joint data, create the bodies from it, and be able to play it as an animation in Unity3D. Any ideas as to how I should go about doing this? I've looked into creating a FBX file from the data but this seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kinect MS SDK in Unity Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7747)
You can use the sdk provided in the link to get bone data on the run for each frame. It has a lot of example code and scene. You can then smooth the positions and rotations optionally.
When you are done with acquiring and smoothing the data, you should have a list of keyframe data. You can use that to create a Unity AnimationClip. If you want to do it the hard way and have more control over the data, you can create your own animation class and update the body transforms with the code you write. This was how I have done it before but I dont suggest it.